# Android resource not found exception. Specify a resource by string

Tags: android, string, android-resources

```
package com.example.tictactoe3d;

import min3d.core.Object3dContainer;
import min3d.core.RendererActivity;
import min3d.parser.IParser;
import min3d.parser.Parser;

import min3d.vos.Light;

public class MainActivity extends RendererActivity {

    private Object3dContainer objModel;

    @Override
    public void initScene() {

        scene.lights().add(new Light());

        IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ,getResources(), "res/raw/camaro_obj" , true);
        parser.parse();

        objModel = parser.getParsedObject();
        //objModel.scale().x = objModel.scale().y = objModel.scale().z = .7f;
        scene.addChild(objModel);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateScene() {
        //objModel.rotation().x++;
        //objModel.rotation().z++;
        scene.camera().position.setAll(0,0,5);
    }
}
```

I am getting a resource not found exception coming out into the log of Eclipse ADT. The min3d library I am using requires to access the resource with a string. I am able to access the resource using R.raw.camaro_obj with the auto complete however the min3d library wants to access that same resource with a string. I have tried:

```
"com.example.tictactoe3d:raw/camaro_obj"

"res/raw/camaro_obj"

"raw/camaro_obj"
```

Is there some way to access the resource "res/raw/camaro_obj" by string somehow?

Thanks...

The call in min3d sample project looks like this:

```
        IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ,getResources(), "min3d.sampleProject1:raw/test2_obj" , true);
```

The code that is actually called by that line is doing this:

```
    public AParser(Resources resources, String resourceID, Boolean generateMipMap)
{
    this();
    this.resources = resources;
    this.resourceID = resourceID;
    if (resourceID.indexOf(":") > -1)
        this.packageID = resourceID.split(":")[0];
    this.generateMipMap = generateMipMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't use a string, you access them by id.  R.raw.camaro_obj  will be an int and you can get an input stream to it by calling `getResources().openRawResources(R.raw.camaro_obj);`

Edit:

I did some googling, this http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html may help

Comment: I understand but if you look at min3d you will find that the call is ""min3d.sampleProject1:raw/test2_obj" which works fine in the sample project. In this case I must supply a string like the one in the sample project.

Comment: I am wondering perhaps if I should just rename and move the sample project which is working... For some reason when I move to a new project I am having a hard time duplicating the way the resources are being accessed.

Comment: I'm not sure yet if it matters but the sample project wants android-4 where the new project I created is android-17. Perhaps is there some change in convention?

Comment: I just put an edit in with the results of some google searching.  It may help